# Execution failed for task ':flutter_native_splash:extractDebugAnnotations'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to use flutter native splash package to display the brand logo of the app, but I've been getting this error below

Execution failed for task ':flutter_native_splash:extractDebugAnnotations'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':flutter_native_splash:detachedConfiguration2'.
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.1.2.
> Required by:
> project :flutter_native_splash
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.1.2.
> Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/30.1.2/lint-gradle-30.1.2.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/30.1.2/lint-gradle-30.1.2.pom'.
> > No such host is known (dl.google.com)
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.1.2.
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/30.1.2/lint-gradle-30.1.2.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/30.1.2/lint-gradle-30.1.2.pom'.
> No such host is known (repo.maven.apache.org)
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.1.2.
> > Could not get resource 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/30.1.2/lint-gradle-30.1.2.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/30.1.2/lint-gradle-30.1.2.pom'.
> > No such host is known (storage.googleapis.com)
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.1.2.
> Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/30.1.2/lint-gradle-30.1.2.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/30.1.2/lint-gradle-30.1.2.pom'.
> > dl.google.com
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.1.2.
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/30.1.2/lint-gradle-30.1.2.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/30.1.2/lint-gradle-30.1.2.pom'.
> > repo.maven.apache.org

Please is there anything i can do to resolve this problem?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific on what you have done!

Comment: I tried using the flutter native splash. This is the error I'm getting in every project I tried it.

Comment: Yes, but HOW did you try? Like, what steps did you use?

Comment: Are you sure you are online when you run?...

Comment: I think I read that the Maven repository has been discontinued. Perhaps that's the problem? Plz show what's inside your .gradle files!

Comment: I added the package under dependencies, set a colour, ran flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create and try to build the app on my android device, but I've been getting this error

Comment: No, I wasn't online when I ran, will try that now

Comment: So? How did it go? 

Comment: Hi! Sorry I'm just getting back. It worked, thanks

Comment: Awesome!  I'll write that as an actual answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These bits:

"Could not resolve all files"... 
"Could not get resource"... 
"Required by"... 
"No such host is known (dl.google.com)"... 
"No such host is known (repo.maven.apache.org)"... 
etc

make me suspect that your IDE is trying to download resources necessary to the functionality you're trying to implement, but failing. The fact that it can't even reach the hosts, or even realize that they exist, makes it seem like you may not have an internet connection.

Check your internet connection, make sure you are online and try again! Hopefully, some stuff will be automatically downloaded, and from there it'll work.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I wasn't connected to the internet.

Comment: Plz click the little check symbol (✔) in the top left corner of my answer, below the vote arrows. That means you "accept" the answer. 